# Leaflet noisy console output

Tags: javascript, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I've started using leaflet maps and I'm having very noisy output in js console. It looks like it's working in some kind of debug mode. It there any option to turn it off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It using angular's [$log](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log), so basically you need to inject `$logProvider` into the config phase of your app and turn it off:

```
app.config(function($logProvider) {
     $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);
});
```

UPDATE:
Note that it will also disable all other places that are using `$log` to output data to the console.